# How do I delete a song from iCloud?

Tags: itunes-match

I updated to iTunes 11.0.2 very recently, and I'm fairly certain this version specifically brought a change of wording regarding deleting songs from iCloud, and I'm curious if there's changed functionality to match.

[image: Dialog for hiding a song in iCloud]

After perusing Apple's support documentation, it seems I was correct:

[image]

I intend to replace the current version of this song, and figured the easiest way to ensure everything updates would be to delete the song from iCloud and my Library, and then import the new version.

Now that the functionality of deleting songs has changed, how do I delete the song from both my local library and iCloud as well?

Comment: Note that this is not a dupe of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36051/stop-devices-deleting-songs-on-icloud-itunes-match nor http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31333/removing-songs-from-icloud because the functionality has changed since those questions were asked, and this is currently a version specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in 11.0.4:

[image: Deleting multiple songs from iCloud]

Comment: My frustration with deleted songs returning led me here. I liked 10.7 and that's what I use on my main Mac. After reading this. I turned on Match on my secondary Mac, and deleted from there using 11. (iTunes 11.0.5) The deleted songs magically left my first Mac. Strange stuff, but glad to have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, the functionality hasn't changed. The first screen shot is what you see when you want to delete an item you have purchased. As part of "iTunes in the Cloud," you can never delete those items, but you can hide them. Deleting from iTunes Match is the same, and that's the second dialog you show.

Comment: I'm not deleting a purchased song. As a matter of fact I'm deleting a song of my own creation, exported as a file from GarageBand. Sounds like a bug in 11.0.2 to me.

Comment: Yes, if that's the case, it's definitely a bug.

Answer (score -2):

I bieleive you are wanting to replace a copy of a song you have in your library and in iCloud. Using iTunes Match I ran into this problem. When you delete a song make sure you select delete from iCloud as well in the pop up to remove it from any device using iTunes Match at the same time.

Comment: That's exactly what this question is asking. There is no option to "delete from iCloud".

Comment: Are you a subscriber to iTunes Match? You won't see the "delete from iCloud" option unless you have a subscription.

Comment: Yes, I am actively subscribed to iTunes Match.

Comment: What is the iCloud status on effected songs?

Comment: It's a self produced/imported song, Uploaded.

Comment: If iTunes is saying the iCloud status of your song is "Uploaded" (meaning it wasn't found in iTunes and a copy was uploaded) you should be able to delete it. Try re-checking your iTunes Match and see if updating your info may help. I've solved problems by updating my Match a few times to make sure all status appear as they should.

Comment: That's the question I'm asking. The original version of the file had been in iTunes Match for months, but it wants to be "hidden". I'm pretty sure this is just an 11.0.2 bug...